# How to install Eclipse which I have already downloaded with Android Development Kit?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have downloaded the full Android Development Kit (ADK) from the official Google Developers website. It is a .zip file which contains Eclipse and other ADT tools.

I want to install the Eclipse application which is in that .zip file. I don't want the trouble of going every time to that particular directory and running Eclipse from there.

Is there any command which lets me *install* the version of Eclipse which I have downloaded with ADK?

[image: this is the picture of eclipse folder]

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/amol/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/amol/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/amol/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclips
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: What's inside the Eclipse zip file? Please add a list of content to your question

Comment: okay..the .zip file contains:adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030 folder in this folder there are two other folder 1)eclipse and 2)sdk

Comment: Ever had a look in the `readme` dir in `eclipse`?

Comment: I have given a picture of eclipse folder..I want to install that eclipse file(that blue one)

Comment: the readme file is so big to read..I just want to install one single file :(

Comment: I'd say you'll have to copy it to `/usr/bin`. But i assume it needs other files to run (config, assets...) So either read the readme for how to install or install eclipse from APT and install Android SDK via the eclipse plugin installer

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command on terminal to give execute permission to the `eclipse` file,

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Documents/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
```

If you wan to run `eclipse` directly from terminal, then add the below line to `~/.bashrc` file.To open `~/.bashrc`, run this command `gedit ~/.bashrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Documents/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse
```

Source `~/.bashrc` file to make it work,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Run the eclipse file directly by,

```
sudo eclipse
```

Comment: amol@4M01:~$ sudo chmod +x ~/Documents/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
[sudo] password for amol: 
amol@4M01:~$ sudo bash ~/Documents/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
/home/amol/Documents/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse: /home/amol/Documents/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse: cannot execute binary file
amol@4M01:~$

Comment: my gedit ~/.bashrc file is already messed up.

Comment: ~$ sudo eclipse
sudo: eclipse: command not found

Comment: Messed up, then post the contents of that file to your question.Did you source ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: You forget to add `e` in eclipse on this line `export PATH=$PATH:/home/amol/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclips` in your bashrc file.